# Not Sure How to Solve A System Of Linear Equations In MAPLE13

Tags: software

How can one solve the following system of linear equations in MAPLE 13?I know how to solve a linear equation with one variable floating around but not this one.
$$x-2y+3z=10$$
$$3x-2y+z=2$$
$$4x+5y+2z=29$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This would be a case where taking a look at the excellent Maple documentation would clearly have been faster than trying to write a post on StackExchange...

Answer (score 2):

You make a set of equations and solve for a set of unknowns:

```
eq1 := x-2*y+3*z = 10; eq2 := 3*x-2*y+z=2; eq3 := 4*x+5*y+2*z = 29; solve({eq1,eq2,eq3},{x,y,z});
```

Comment: Great.Thanks.Is there any way of telling maple to show steps?

Comment: Since it's home work, this is the point where you should consult a good book on linear algebra... You should then be able to explain how Maple gets to the solution.

Comment: I'am trying to solve $$eqn1 := x-6*y+7*z = 7; eqn2 := 4*x-5*y+9*z = 8; eqn3 := -2*x+4*y+5*z = 10; solve({eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x, y, z})$$,and i get $$x = 1, y = 3, z = 5$$ as solution which is completely wrong.What should i do?

Comment: @alok you did not put curly braces around your equation set and your unknown set. see my answer

Comment: @alok: As far as I'm aware, you can't ask maple to show the intermediary steps between the problem setup and the solution.  You can illustrate the intermediary steps yourself by multiplying the matrix and right hand side vector by elementary matrices that produce the row operations.  But this must be done manually.

Comment: @alok Write this as a matrix problem, then use `Student[LinearAlgebra][LinearSolveTutor]` to be guided while doing the steps yourself - or hit "next step" when stuck. See the help page [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/LinearAlgebra/LinearSolveTutor). You'll need to choose between pure Gaussian and Gauss-Jordan solving. You can use [GenerateMatrix](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/LinearAlgebra/GenerateMatrix) to convert equations to matrix form (use option `augmented=false`), or edit the system after invoking the tutor.